# Why doesnt the recursive function below end when return is called?

Tags: c, recursion

```
#define LIMIT 1000
void fun2(int n)
{
  if (n <= 0)
     return;
  if (n > LIMIT)
    return;
  printf("%d ", n);
  fun2(2*n);
  printf("%d ", n);
}   `
```

The code will output n, 2n, 4n, 8n, ... for values less than LIMIT. But then it prints in reverse order. For example, fun2(100) will print 100, 200, 400, 800, 800, 400, 200, 100. Why doesnt it just print up to 800 then quit once return is called?

I have tried going line by line but I dont understand it. I am still learning recursive functions in c.

Comment: ***I have tried going line by line but I dont understand it.*** Make the LIMIT much smaller so your debugging task is manageable. 1000 is way too much.

Comment: That is what recursion does, it builds up a stack of calls to fun2 up to 800. Then all the calls start returning and the line after the calls starts printing their input n again (which is the lower value). So it does exactly what it should do

Comment: take a pen and paper - execute it yourself (you will be the computer)

Comment: `return` just stop the current function, not the functions calling that "inner" function (even if they have the same name).

Comment: When a function it returns, it returns to where it was called. It was called before the second `printf`, and thus returns there.

Comment: One of the key concepts that you must grasp to understand recursion is that every *execution* of a function is separate from all other executions of that (or any other) function.  In particular, if we're being precise, we never return from a function.  Rather, we return from the current *execution* of a function.  When a function recurses, you have two or more executions of the same function in progress at the same time.  After control returns from one, execution of the previous proceeds.

Answer (score 2):

the function prints in reverse order because you call `printf("%d ", n);` two times, one before calling the function and one after.

So the execution goes like this:

First you call the function with a value, if its greater than zero and less than LIMIT it will print the value and call another time the function but with `2*n`, so the process repeats until the value is greater than LIMIT, in which case the function will return (nothing because is of type void) to its caller, so the previous function that call it will continue its execution, will print the second `printf("%d ", n);` and exit and will return to its caller, which will do the same, execute `printf("%d ", n);` this will repeat until the first calling function which will return to the caller of the `fun2()`, for example main.

Hope you understand, if not, there is plenty of information about recursive functions in C. Try reading the [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) it will help.